# Does deleting migrations and database in dev, cause issues when pushing to production?

Tags: django, django-models

I had a conflict in my development database, so to make things easier for me I deleted all my migrations and dropped database and created a new one. Now in development every thing works correctly:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete

dropdb 'mydb'
createdb 'mydb'

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I then saved a git commit and pushed to production and got the following error:
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "shop_id" of relation "subscribers_subscriber" already exists`

Note: I am using a postgresql database

Should I not have deleted my development database?

Comment: Have you managed to figured out the problem? If so, feel free to post a solution and accept your own answer.