# On migrating in django project it shows and error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, migration

` from django.db import models
from .category import Category
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

```
color_choices = ((1, 'red'),
                (2, 'Black'),
                (3, 'White'))


class Products(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/product_images/', default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=0)
    offer = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    color = MultiSelectField(choices=color_choices, max_choices=3, max_length=3, 
 default=3)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1052, default='')`
```

**ERROR**
"ValueError: Field 'stock' expected a number but got 'UNAVAILABLE'."
here I even removed the field  'stock ' from model but still getting error. It is not migrating.....
What I do now? Please Help?
[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxxhl.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgPoh.png)[admin.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYrbs.png)

Comment: can you add your models.py file so we can see how the models are arranged

Comment: I sent screenshot . now where I can add models file

Comment: please copy the code using the supplied markup rather than a screenshot

Comment: very sorry to say I don't know how to add code but now uploaded screenshots you can see them. and please help, I am stuck for an hour.

Comment: @Sirwill98 Thanks GOD finally added code Now you can see

Comment: can you remove all the products from the db then try migrate, it seems like your db is expecting 1 value but the field stock has been given another

Comment: @Sirwill98 I removed all products and than migrated but still getting the error

Comment: are you creating a product manually anywhere in the code? and is the error caused when you migrate?

Comment: No, I am creating products from admin panel of django and also removing from there.

Comment: can you show your admin.py

Comment: when you had stock in your model did you give it a default value?

Comment: @Sirwill98 Added screenshot.. you can see now

Comment: Yes I gave It a defult value

Comment: what was the default value?

Comment: first it was 'UNAVAILABLE' than I changes to number 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from your original default being "unavailable" this cannot be used for an integer field.

You will need to delete the faulty migrations then update your model with the correct data type for the default e.g. 0 then run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: How can I remove faulty migrations....?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000680/django-safely-remove-old-migrations
you can follow this on how to remove faulty or oldmigrations

Comment: ok Let me try ..Thank you

Comment: if it was what you were looking for please mark it as answered so anyone in the future can use this to help them too